# Sort a List in C# by a Columncollection

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

Hey I have some Kind of a Column Property List, Containing Information like HeaderName etc.
And I have a Datagrid bound to a List of Items, the Columns are the sime like the Column Property List.

So now the User has the possibility to adjust position and width of the visible columns. That can be only 3 of 30 possible columns.
But I want to save the "sorted" part of the List into the old list.

Okay, hesre my first approach:

```
var columns = grid.Columns.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayIndex);

        var prop = DynamicManager.GetPropertyGridByTableNameGroupLanguage("Article", 1, 1);
        var orderesProp = from o in columns
                          join i in prop
                          on o.Header.ToString() equals i.PropertyName
                          orderby o.DisplayIndex
                          select new TableProperty
                          {
                              DbPropertyType = i.DbPropertyType,
                              GroupingProperty = i.GroupingProperty,
                              Mandatory = i.Mandatory,
                              MandatoryDB = i.MandatoryDB,
                              MaxValue = i.MaxValue,
                              MaxValueDB = i.MaxValueDB,
                              MinValue = i.MinValue,
                              MinValueDB = i.MinValueDB,
                              PropertyImportCode = i.PropertyImportCode,
                              PropertyName = i.PropertyName,
                              ReadOnly = i.ReadOnly,
                              Searchable = i.Searchable,
                              UIPropertyName = i.UIPropertyName,
                              UIPropertyType = i.UIPropertyType,
                              Visible = i.Visible,
                              VisibleInGrid = i.VisibleInGrid,
                              Width = o.ActualWidth
                          };
```

When I first select from columns, I get the List ordered correctly, but only 3 of 31 entries. When I select prop first and then join the columns, I have still the complete List, but not sorted correctly by displayindex.

Do you have any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
  var orderesProp = from i in prop
                          select new { i = i, o = columns.FirstOrDefault(x => i.Name == x.Name) } into merge
                          orderby merge.o == null ? int.MaxValue : merge.o.DisplayIndex
                          select merge.i;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but your solution seems not to work for me. Its still not the right sort of the List :/

Comment: can you clarify what is wrong? In my sample app I get all elements of prop and list starts with elements corresponding to visible columns in display order and then all other (not visible) elements fallow.

Comment: I sorted the Grid by Number, Code and Name, but in the orderesProp the sort of the values is not sorted liek this.
Also even "not visible" objects are  inbetween the list, so its not items with column index first and then the rest :(